# How to force a running migration to stop

Tags: drush, migrations

I created a migration with a query that seems to have broken my migration. I added two groupBy on a query, instead of two orderBys. As a result, running drush mi MyMigration got stuck in what appeared to be an endless loop.

I CTRL-C'd the process and then ran a drush mst --all, but now the status is reporting as "Stopping" in the UI, and the drush ms command does not return.

I tried stoping and restarting MAMP, but to no effect.

Is there someway to force my migration to get unstuck?

Comment: There are many "migration" modules, please tell us exactly what you are using and how it is configured.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try `migrate-reset-status`, and possibly with `--force`:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1561820

Otherwise I typically restart PHP manually once (restart your webserver) and then use Drush to `rollback` all the migrations to try again fresh.

**EDIT**

I rarely use the UI as everything is usable and scriptable via `drush` when using Migrate. And trying to use a webserver to check the status of long-running tasks can be error-prone.

Comment: I tried migrate-reset-status. It did allow me to rollback the migration - or at least appears to have. However, I still cannot get the status (drush ms status), and the UI shows that the migration is still stopping.  I also restarted MAMP - and my desktop afterwards, to no affect. Not sure how to flush this state?

Comment: Try `migrate-register`. Again `drush help migrate-register` to see what it does. I recommend reading about every migrate command over a coffee: `drush help --filter=migrate` and then read the `drush help COMMAND` per command.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
drush php-eval "var_dump(Drupal::keyValue('migrate_status')->set('migration_id', 0));"
```

Comment: I'm unlucky, hasn't worked for me yet: `set('migration_id', 0));"
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 1: `set -eu && ( /mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/drush php-eval var_dump(Drupal::keyValue('migrate_status')->set('migration_id', 0));)'`